# static factory Dependency Injection with external dependency

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

How can we create beans in Spring context to inject the dependencies?

I am able to create `MainFactory` by specifying the `factory-method = "newInstance"`, but for the instances created, like `FirstCSVConcrete()` or `FirstXLSConcrete()`. I also need to inject `TotalReport` bean. so, how we can inject the external dependencies while creating the factory in Spring context.

My requirement to represent below code snippet with Spring DI and create beans for both `MainFactory` and `TotalReport`. Also, I don't want to pass `TotalReport` to `newInstance()` method.

```
public class MainFactory {
    private FirstInterface firstInterface;
    private MainFactory(String type){
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("CSV")){
            firstInterface = new FirstCSVConcrete();
        } else {
            firstInterface = new FirstXLSConcrete();
        }
    }
    public static MainFactory newInstance(String type){
        return new MainFactory(type);
    }
}

public class FirstCSVConcrete implements FirstInterface {
    TotalReport totalReport;
}

public class FirstXLSConcrete implements FirstInterface {
    TotalReport totalReport;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Instantiate beans of type `FirstCSVConcrete` and `FirstXLSConcrete` normally, that is:

```
@Component
public class FirstCSVConcrete implements FirstInterface { 
    @Autowired
    private TotalReport totalReport;
}
```

same for `FirstXLSConcrete` as well.

Now, setup your `MainFactory` as follows:

```
public class MainFactory {

    @Autowired
    private FirstCSVConcrete firstCSVConcrete;

    @Autowired
    private FirstXLSConcrete firstXLSConcrete;


    private String type;

    public static MainFactory newInstance(String type){
        return new MainFactory(type);
    }

    private MainFactory(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    private FirstInterface selectedFirstInterface = null;
    public FirstInterface getFirstInterface() {
        if(selectedFirstInterface == null) {
            selectedFirstInterface = selectFirstInterfaceForType(type);
        }
        return selectedFirstInterface;
    }

    private FirstInterface selectFirstInterfaceForType(String type) {
        if("CSV".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            return firstCSVConcrete;
        }
        return firstXLSConcrete;
    }
}
```

`Spring` cannot inject dependencies into the objects that you instantiate yourself. So, you'll have to go with this approach, or one the variations thereof.

**Solution 2: much more neat; using aspectj with Spring**

```
@Component
public class TotalReport {
    ...
}

@Configurable
public class FirstXLSConcrete implements FirstInterface {

    @Autowired
    private TotalReport totalReport;

    ...
}

@Configurable
public class FirstCSVConcrete implements FirstInterface {
    @Autowired
    private TotalReport totalReport;

}

public class MainFactory {

    private FirstInterface firstInterface;

    private MainFactory(String type) {
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("CSV")) {
            firstInterface = new FirstCSVConcrete();
        } else {
            firstInterface = new FirstXLSConcrete();
        }
        System.out.println(firstInterface.getTotalReport());
    }

    public static MainFactory newInstance(String type) {
        return new MainFactory(type);
    }

}
```

declare the following in your application-context configuration file:

```
<context:load-time-weaver />
<context:spring-configured />
```

create a `context.xml` in your application's `META-INF` diretory and put the following in there.

```
<Context path="/youWebAppName">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"
        useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false"/>
</Context>
```

put Spring's `spring-tomcat-weaver.jar` (probably named `org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-<version>.jar`) in your tomcat installation's `lib` directory, and voila, the aspectj magic starts working. For classes that are annotated with [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) annotation, the `@Autowired` dependencies are resolved automatically; even if the instances are created outside of the spring-container.

I guess the answer has become quite long now. If you want more details, here is the link to [using aspectj with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html). There are several configuration options as well. Knock yourself out.